# Is there a way to make a type hint for multiple returns

Tags: python, type-hinting

I want to specify my function with correct type hints for return values.
My function receives data as a dictionary and returns the modification. It also returns a status code as integer to check if the modification was successfull. For example I want to specify something like this:

```
def reworkData(measurement:dict)->dict,int:
   ...
   return measurement,0
```

This currently results in invalid syntax. How can I do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From Python 3.5 to 3.8 you want [`Tuple[dict, int]`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Tuple) in order to specify that you will return both as Python will return them as a tuple.

```
from typing import Tuple

def rework_data(measurement: dict) -> Tuple[dict, int]:
   ...
   return measurement, 0
```

As of Python 3.9 `Tuple` is deprecated and you should use the builtin type

```
def rework_data(measurement: dict) -> tuple[dict, int]:
   ...
   return measurement, 0
```

Comment: Yes, this is the right answer. Union is for when both types are accepted (e.g. str and Path).

Answer (score 1):

If you have multiple returns the way you do, you're returning a tuple of values `(measurement,0)`. So, you should specify the return as such:

```
def reworkData(measurement:dict)->(dict,int):
   ...
   return measurement,0
```

**Note:**

In some environments, as discussed in the comments, this will still throw a SyntaxError (most likely due to style-checkers used).

Comment: Interesting, I knew about using `typing.Tuple` but I didn't know you could specify it directly like this.

Comment: Yes, I'm not sure which one is better. I'd be interested to hear if anyone knows if there're advantages/disadvantages of using one method over the other.

Comment: You can't, this results in a SyntaxError https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.10&gist=966ebadefdb55ec3154dd875938c2b96

Comment: I know they've been trying to move away from some of the `typing` definitions and towards more native Python syntax for the type hints, so it's possible that this way will be the preferred one.

Comment: @AlexWaygood Works fine for me in Python 3.8 and PyCharm is happy to accept it as valid syntax. I think that error is a quirk of the style checker that site uses.

Comment: I already tried this solution but I avoided it because it results in an error in vs code that says: "Tuple expression not allowed in type annotation". But it works, thanks :)

Comment: @AlexWaygood that is weird, I'm on Python 3.8.5 and have no issue with this.

Comment: Maybe it's the case that runtime Python and PyCharm are fine with it, but MyPy/VSCode struggle with it? But idk, that's strange.

Comment: @StefanMaier Honestly, I'd probably accept the other answer, since this seems to cause issues in certain environments (although as mentioned might not do so in the future)

Comment: FWIW I much prefer the `(dict, int)` syntax to the `tuple[dict, int]` syntax, so it's a shame MyPy seems not to like it.

Comment: @dm2 doing it your way seems to be the more intuitive way.

Comment: @StefanMaier fair enough, it's just that Kemp's answer is more universal (at least at the moment) and would have more chance of working for people searching the same issue. This is however your question, so if you think this should be the accepted answer, I've got no issue with that :)